# OculusGo remote random position issue

Tags: oculusgo

I am developing an application using Unity and OculusGo headset.Application is interacting with objects using OculusGo remote controller. But sometimes what happens, OculusGo remote is located at random positions. Sometimes it goes too behind from the original position or sometimes it goes too ahead from the original position. If this problem occurs and I restart the application it gives me accurate position.

Note: I am not changing position of camera or remote at run time and it is having fixed position through out the application.

Can you please help me in this problem?